# Crashlytics Framework doesn't detect the Info plist on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, crashlytics

I am trying to add Crashlytics framework in my project, however, when I go through the process and reach the point where I add the framework to the project. The "Fabric" script plugin on the Mac doesn't detect that the frame work has been add to the project, and I think because the it doesn't detect the Info.plist in my project as I have changed the name of the Info.plist to something else. I have tried to change it back to Info.plist but still doesn't work.
How can I make the framework to detect the info.plist in my project.

Thanks

Comment: do you see any compiler output ?

Comment: You probably shouldn't change the name of the info.plist. Clean your build by pressing `command+shift+k`. Also verify that the frameworks have been added under Target > Build Phases > Link Binary With Libraries.

Comment: You need to add both `Crashlytics.framework` and `Fabric.framework` to the app; however you do not need to start any of the Fabric stuff (just start Crashlytics) and you don't need to use the Fabric `run` script (use the Crashlytics `run` script).

Comment: Alex from Fabric here. I agree that it doesn't seem like an issue with your info.plist. There are a couple of things we can investigate but it'd be super helpful to look at some of your logs and get your bundle id. Might be easiest to handle through support@fabric.io and I can post the answer here once we have it figured out!

Answer (score 25):

I'm not sure if what I encountered was the same thing, but when trying to archive my project, I received the following error:

> ❌ error: Fabric: Info.plist Error

I poked through the output in XCode which mentioned it could be a timing issue and to make sure that I made the "Fabric" build phase one of the last build phases.  So I updated the XCode configuration and made the Fabric step run just before the "Upload Symbols to Fabric" step, and this cleared up the issue. See the image below.

[image: XCode Build Phases]

Comment: This solution worked for me with Fabric 2.3.1 and XCode 7.2

Comment: Best solution for this problem, move Fabric script at the end of Build Phases

Comment: Best solution, i had the same and moving fabric script at the end of build phases solved for me also

Answer (score 8):

The root cause for me was an **empty Bundle Identifier** (although the key was set in info.plist).

[image]

After setting up a new XCode-project as a copy of another one i copied the info.plist with all keys into the new project. But it uses variables like $(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER), which was assigned somewhere else (maybe in the project file, that i haven't copied also)

In the screenshot the field with the round oval was empty then as a result. After applying the correct bundle identifier, everything has built fine.

Answer (score 8):

**Xcode 10 only:**

Add your app's built Info.plist location to the Build Phase's Input Files field:

```
$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/$(INFOPLIST_PATH)
```

Comment: I added this in Embed Pods Frameworks's Input Files filed. And the error went on :)

Answer (score 6):

Move the *RunScript in Target -> Build Phase* to the last and give it a try:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Did you add the Fabric `NSDictionary` entry to your .plist(s)?

[image]

Comment: Yes I did that but still doesn't work. However, this dictionary should be added automatically when you run the "Fabric" script.

Comment: I ran into some problems when migrating with the plist entry

Answer (score 2):

Set absolute path of Info.plist in "Input Files"

- Add/Change "Input Files" value in Run Script added for Fabric under "Build Phases"
- From "$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/$(INFOPLIST_PATH)" To "**new path***/Info.plist"

***new path**: You can also get Info.plist path from Build Settings -> Packaging -> Info.plist File

[image: Plist file path]

Answer (score 0):

Add your app's built Info.plist location to the Build Phase's Input Files field:

$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/$(INFOPLIST_PATH)

Note: Put exact same lines as given above to resolve this issue I am using Xcode_10.1 and this is working perfectly fine for me and on **Fabric official website they specifically mention the same solution as given above**[Please refer this image to see attached screenshots  of Xcode to get more details about where to put this line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AT8TU.png)

Answer (score -1):

Xcode 10 only:

Add your app's built Info.plist location to the Build Phase's Input Files field:

$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/$(INFOPLIST_PATH)

at the same time, Move the runscript to the last row.